# web3 installed but not accessible using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, web3py

web3 is already installed (using pip3) but in different path.

I tried many ways to import web3 but its shows no module named web3 every time.

I have already tried pip install as well as pip3 install but none is solving the issue.

how can I solve the issue?

> Python 3.5.0 (default, Aug 31 2018, 06:38:24)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> from web3 import Web3
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named 'web3'

Comment: you have installed it using global python -> pip or in a virtual env?

Comment: just try once with pip --install upgrade web3 and check if that works or not.

Comment: yes web3 module issue is solved but got another issue

Comment: ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cytoolz/functoolz.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf